# Parser for OsmInEdit

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a project to do where I have to programm a parser that parses SVG flight plans of buildings into OSM.
In OsmInEdit, you can manually edit indoor maps. I want this to be done automatically. Do you have an idea how I can access the OSM database in an automated matter?  [I can only find the graphical interface for manual editing](https://osminedit.pavie.info/#18/48.13678/-1.69533).

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and write access to the OSM database for editing purposes is available through the [Editing API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API). This includes all OSM data, there are no specialized APIs for topics such as indoor mapping. Have a look at the relevant documentation on the OSM wiki (e.g. [Simple Indoor Tagging](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_Indoor_Tagging)) to understand the subset of OSM data you're interested in.

Note that the OSM project has [rules for automated edits](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Automated_Edits_code_of_conduct) and [for imports](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines), so please don't run your software on the real instance of the database without the community's consent.

If your focus is on parsing these plans and converting them to the OSM data model, rather than the actual uploading, consider having your software output data in the [OSM XML file format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML). This is supported by many OSM tools, such as editors, and libraries for reading and writing such files exist for most popular development platforms.